# Configure .htacces for public folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have the following folder structure in a php project:

`project/
 |--app/
 |--public/
     |--img/
     |--.htaccess
     |--index.php
 |--vendor/`

How would the .htacces file be in order to serve the `public` folder from `host.domain/project/` ?

I'm guessing the .htaccess would need to be in the root folder. I could also edit the servers virtual host file for `host.domain` but I don't know how would the configuration be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to mix a public folder system with an old one

The website is like

- / -> `/public/index.php?route=/`
- /mypage -> `/public/index.php?route=/mypage`
- /fakefolder/mypage -> `/public/index.php?route=/fakefolder/mypage`
- /fakefolder/mypage?a=b&foo=bar -> `/public/index.php?route=/fakefolder/mypage&a=b&foo=bar` (this works because of [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag of Apache2)

All static files present in /public/ are accessible, for example `/assets/img/foo.png` is at `/public/assets/img/foo.png` on file system

And the admin system works the "old way"

- /admin/ -> /admin/index.php
- /admin/login -> /admin/login.php

```
RewriteEngine on

# Already in admin folder, use admin folder, old routing system
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
# It is a folder, do not re-write it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Do not hit this once more if it already is a file, .php was already added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/$1.php [L,QSA]

# See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957084/5155484
# Not already in public folder or admin folder, use public folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]


# Use router if it was redirected by previous pass to public folder
# And it is not a file, that way files are served as static files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public
# Do not hit this once more if it already is a file, .php was already added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you change `/` to `./` for the `RewriteRule` on some production servers you will have an error 500.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the main/virtual host configuration, you can set the [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) to the `public` folder

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/project/public
```

---

If you cannot do that, or want to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and `project` is the document root, you can do a rewrite to `public`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't work. It may be because the public folder also has a .htaccess.

I tried:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]`
and more similar variations.

I'll have to wait to get a domain or subdomain and then add a VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: @Jedabero What is the error you get? And how does the `/public/.htaccess` look like?